# Destructors and shutdown functions when exiting by Ctrl+C in PHP-CLI

Tags: php

If I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to exit a PHP script running in CLI, neither the shutdown functions, nor the destructors of instantiated objects, nor any output buffers are handled. Instead the program just dies. Now, this is probably a good thing, since that's what <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is supposed to do. But is there any way to change that? Is it possible to force <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to go through the shutdown functions?

More specifically, this is about serialising and saving data on exiting of the script, so it can be reloaded and resumed the next time the script runs. Periodically saving the data could work, but would still lose everything from the last save onward. What other options are there?

Comment: Have you considered trying Ctrl+Z?  I don't know if that works with PHP or not...

Comment: I'm not sure what Ctrl+Z is supposed to do. I just tried it and it doesn't seem to do anything, other than cause a ^Z character to appear on the next prompt that appears (be it an `fgets(STDIN)` or the new prompt after a Ctrl+C)

Comment: I haven't done PHP CLI in a while but is there a way to periodically look grab CLI input and listen for a specific "kill" command and then initiate the deconstructor?? You could also set a "kill" flag in a config file for your script and routinely check for that flag.

Comment: Looks like you're out of luck with Windows: [PHP doesn't support signal handling on Windows. Sorry.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3333291/895378)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Obviously PCNTL is *nix only, but ... You can register handlers for all the individual signals for a more robust solution, but specifically to do something when a CTL+C interrupt is encountered:

```
<?php
declare(ticks = 1);

pcntl_signal(SIGINT, function() {
    echo "Caught SIGINT\n";
    die;
});

while (true) {
    // waiting for your CTRL+C
}
```

Comment: Ah, I should have mentioned I'm on Windows...

Comment: Doh! Bill Gates hates you! I'm not aware of any way to accomplish this in windows ...

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [PCNTL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcntl.php) especially [pcntl_signal()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-signal.php)

Answer (score 1):

I contrast to [the answer by @rdlowrey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13370031/2432317), I would avoid a plain `while(true)` as well as that `die/exit` in the `pcntl_signal` function as it does not allow handling things after the loop has been user-interrupted.

Instead, I’ld like to suggest the following, more logic solution:

```
declare(ticks = 1);

$running = true;

pcntl_signal(SIGINT, function() {
    global $running;
    $running = false;
});

while($running)
{
    echo('running…'.PHP_EOL);
}

echo(PHP_EOL.'User interrupted the loop. Shutting down cleanly.'.PHP_EOL);
exit();
```